# How to stop wkhtmltopdf.exe popping up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I created a GUI Program in python to create pdfs.I am using pdfkit library to create pdfs :

```
options = {
      'page-size': 'A4',
      'margin-top': '0.3in',
      'margin-bottom': '0.3in',
      'margin-left': '0.5in',  
      'margin-right': '0.4in',
      'quiet': '',
      'orientation' : 'Landscape'                   
      }
    toc = {
    'xsl-style-sheet': 'toc.xsl'
    } 

    path_wkhtmltopdf = r'wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
    pdfkit.from_string(htmlString, reportPath, configuration=config, toc=toc, options = options)
```

To make an  executable of my GUI program, I used `pyinstaller`.
When I use this .exe file , it pops-up a cmd window of  wkhtmltopdf.exe during creation of pdf . How can I stop from popping up? After research on internet I did not find any solution.

Comment: i cannot figure out how to use the toc. can you help me? i assume i will need a .xsl file. but i don't know much about that doc type nor what i should put in there. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not straight forward, but the popup window is from a command called by the module `subprocess` that is defaulted to creating a window when the executable from `wkhtmltopdf` is called.

> subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
>
> ```
> The new process has a new console, instead of inheriting its parent’s console (the default).
> ```

Since there is no way to pass that argument through `pdfkit`, you can locate the module to make the change before building from `pyinstaller`. The method describes below works for me on Windows and Python 3.X.

---

**Locate and change the `subprocess` setting that creates the window**

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.pdfkit
#THIS LOCATES THE FILE YOU NEED TO CHANGE

Output:
<module 'pdfkit.pdfkit' from '\\lib\\site-packages\\pdfkit\\pdfkit.py'>
```

**Edit the file from the link you have in the following part, the added paramters are with comments;**

```
def to_pdf(self, path=None):

        #CREATE AN ADDITIONAL PARAMTER
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000

        args = self.command(path)

        result = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE,

                                  #PASS YOUR PARAMETER HERE
                                  creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW )
```

And save the file, this passes the required parameter that suppresses the creation of a window.

Once you are done with that, you should be able to rebuild your program.

**Example program**

Save the following code with a `.pyw` extension that basically means a no-console script from Python, for example `html2pdf.pyw`. Make sure you replace the paths with yours.

```
import pdfkit

path_wkhtmltopdf = 'your wkhtmltopdf.exe path'
out_path = 'the output file goes here'


config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 
                out_path, 
                configuration = config)
```

Locate the `html2pdf.pyw` folder and build with `pyinstaller`: `pyinstaller html2pdf`.

Finally test your program with the executable located in the same folder under `dist\html2pdf\html2pdf.exe`.

Comment: You are the lifesaver! I would say this solution is quite straightforward and easy to implement. Although, it worked also without saving the script with .pyw extension.

Comment: Yeah, `.pyw` is just to suppress the Python console if any. Hope that helped, in any case a step further if you think useful is to suggest an option to pass `args` into `pdfkit` to pass the parameter without changing the original library code.